# Problem with basics queries form dbpedia with sparql

Tags: sparql, dbpedia

Why can get results with this query:

```
SELECT *
              WHERE {
                ?person rdfs:label "Kirk Douglas"@en;
                dbo:birthPlace ?place. # With dbp: too
              }
```

but not with another one:

```
SELECT *
              WHERE {
                ?person rdfs:label "Kirk Douglas"@en;
                dbo:starring ?film.
              }
```

I'm following tags in https://dbpedia.org/page/Kirk_Douglas

Some tip to understand it.

Thx!

Answer (score 1):

In [dbr:Kirk_Douglas](https://dbpedia.org/page/Kirk_Douglas) you can read:

```
dbo:birthPlace     dbr:Amsterdam_(city),_New_York
...
is dbo:starring of dbr:The_Light_at_the_Edge_of_the_World
                   dbr:Cast_a_Giant_Shadow
                   dbr:Two-Fisted_Tales_(film)
                   ...
```

where `is dbo:starring of` is a way of simulating an [*inverse property*](https://www.w3.org/TR/owl-syntax/#Inverse_Object_Properties_2) for `dbo:starring`.

Indeed, in [dbo:starring](https://dbpedia.org/ontology/starring) you can read:

```
rdfs:domain dbo:Work
...
rdfs:range dbo:Actor
```

This means that you shouldn't build triples like `?actor dbo:starring ?work`, while `?work dbo:starring ?actor` is a valid triple.

So your query should be something like:

```
SELECT *
WHERE {
  ?person rdfs:label "Kirk Douglas"@en .
  ?film dbo:starring ?person .
}
```